# C# XAML CoreWindowDialog alternatives for Windows IoT

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am writing an  UWP app for a Raspbery Pi 3 which runs Windows IoT.
Unfortunately Win IoT doesnt support the class "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialog" ([look here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=889950&sid=7fd32222efdd204614ae0bf58edc8f89#p889950))

I want it to look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkR4E9PQEns&feature=youtu.be&t=1m23s).

Are there any similar classes which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) to represents a dialog for showing messages.